# PyArrow: mmap-backed pass-through array?

Tags: python, arrays, mmap, pyarrow, apache-arrow

In [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/), what is a proper way to construct an mmap-backed pass-through array,
meaning: to have a fixed-size, fixed-schema [pyarrow.Array](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.array.html) backed by a buffer, which is based on a [pyarrow.MemoryMappedFile](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.memory_map.html), such that changes to the array are directly reflected on the file system, even after the process crash?

Comment: `pyarrow.Array` is immutable, so I you can't have "changes to the array"

Comment: ok, are there any array-like structures in apache arrow that support pass-through mmap?